# How to detect what wattage that my Windows laptop is receiving via USB-PD?

Tags: windows, usb, charging, voltage, usb-pd

I don't know too much about USB-PD. I understood that USB-PD requires negotiation between the charger and the receiver. So probably my Windows laptop (Dell XPS 9570) should be able to know the current wattage input it's receiving. Windows probably also know since it's popping up saying slow charging. So I'm curious to know what wattage is my Dell is getting and is it getting the 100w it supposed to get?

My setup is a Dell XPS 9570 connected to Razer Core X Chroma eGPU. I've tried two cables, the Thunderbolt that came with the Razer Core X and the Apple Thunderbolt 3 0.8m, both of them still give that slow charging pop up.

Cheers!

Comment: MacOS has the terminal command `system_profiler SPPowerDataType`, which tells you the incoming watts. Does any one know if Windows has a similar command? I've tried `powercfg -ENERGY` but that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the wattage being drawn with a USB power tester like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DCTG6LH).

Are you sure whatever you are using to deliver the power is capable of 100W?  From what I have seen, there are few USB-PD devices that deliver that much power.  You are probably using a lower power charger, which is why you are getting that warning.

Comment: Yes, it is stated in the spec that the Razer Core X should be able to deliver up to 100W. Actually, I'm curious if the USB power tester like the one you suggested can work with an eGPU box?

Comment: @sasawatc There is no reason it shouldnt.